How can the union of sets be seen to be an example of a pushout?
In the well answered question here, the following example of a pushout is given:
The union of sets can be constructed as a pushout. Given sets $A$ and $B$, we have $A \cap B \subseteq A$ and $A \cap B \subseteq B$. Let $i_A : A \cap B \to A$ and $i_B : A \cap B \to B$ be the inclusions. Then $A \cup B$ is (naturally isomorphic to) the pushout of $i_A$ and $i_B$. Working through the verification of this fact would be a good exercise to help you understand pushouts.
I've worked through the other examples provided on this post but I'm unable to verify the example I have referenced above.
I believe the task is to find maps $j_A: A \to A \cup B$ and $j_B: B \to A \cup B$ such that $j_A \circ i_A = j_B \circ i_A$. I.e. that we have a commutative square.
To have these maps commute (I think) I need the preimage of points in $A \cup B$ which are mapped to by $j_A$ and $j_B$ to be equal. In the same way that in the other given example on the referenced question, we have an equivalence relation $f(x) \sim g(x)$.
I cannot however think what functions I need to complete the pushout $(A \cup B, j_A, j_B)$.
Potentially $j_A: id_A$ and $j_B: id_B$ might do what I need, but I'm not certain.
Thank you in advance.

The maps completing the pushout are the obvious inclusions $A \to A \cup B$ and $B \to A \cup B$. The way you construct them in set theory has little to do with category theory, but you can just send $a \in A$ to $a \in A \cup B$ and similarly for $B$. Also that is not what it means for the square to commute: you want $j_A(i_A(x)) = j_B(i_B(x))$ for all $x \in A \cap B$.
